Right censoring deaths in length of stay studies
I've been doing some reading on length of stay studies in intensive care units. There are competing events with length of stay and death. For example, a treatment may be more effective at reducing length of stay because it is a truly effective treatment, or it it could reduce length of stay by causing more deaths.
I've seen an approach where patients are censored after the follow-up date. For example, in the RECOVERY trial, "Patients who die in hospital will be censored after 28 days after randomisation" link.
Doesn't this approach overestimate the median length of stay in hospital by censoring these patients at the end of follow-up?

Can you say what 'censored' means here, please?

@RobbieGoodwin it's probably better to say that the time to the event is censored rather than the patient. In that context, this is right censoring, which means that there is only a lower limit known for the time to the event: it hadn't happened yet by the last time the patient was observed.

Yes, it does tend to overestimate median length of stay.
The RECOVERY trial isn't estimating median length of stay, it's estimating time to discharge alive. That's a bit different. Someone who dies in hospital at day 50 has 50 days in hospital and so censoring at 25 will underestimate median length of stay.
But that same hypothetical person has no time to discharge alive: they aren't getting discharged alive, no matter how long you wait.  So, the question is how do you code them for time to discharge alive. One reasonable approach is to code their time to discharge alive as censored at the end of time. That's what the cumulative incidence analysis for competing risks does (effectively; there are complications in variance estimation).  The RECOVERY document goes on to say "This gives an unbiased estimate of the
recovery rate and comparable estimates to the competing risks approach in the absence of other censoring". I would assume the competing risks approach is the one I mentioned, and that it doesn't make much difference because not many people are discharged alive after 28 days
Similarly, they say "Successful cessation of invasive mechanical ventilation will be defined as removal of invasive mechanical ventilation within (and survival to) 28 days after randomisation" and deaths are coded as censored after 28 days. Again, successful is key here; it's not just a economic/workload analysis of ventilator-days, where you would introduce bias.

Thanks for pointing out the subtlety in time to discharge alive vs median length of stay.
